# Syntax error when run in as step in SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016

Below scripts works perfectly fine, when you run it in PowerShell window.

```
Import-Csv $DestinationFile | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "INSERT INTO $table VALUES ('$($SourceFile)','$($_.LineNumber)','$($_.LineDescription)','$($_.Criteria)','$($_.LineValue)')"
}
```

But when you run this script through SQL Server Agent job ... it gives syntax error.

Also below mentioned line doesn't work when scheduled as a job.

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false # $false
```

Using PowerShell, we search the docs and based on pattern search, results we found... we import them into the database.

All working good when you run in PowerShell console, but when you try to run PS1 file through SQL Server it doesn't do anything.

Comment: What does the error say? How did you create the job? Is the SQL Server PowerShell module installed?

Comment: how to check whether sql server powershell module is installed

Comment: when you install it as a job - under type... you get option of POWERSHELL....

Comment: Does `Get-Module -ListAvailable` show the module `SqlServer`? Which SQL Server version are you using in the first place?

Comment: SQL 2016 we are using, and I also imported Import-module sqlps

Comment: With your last edit it's even less clear what the problem might be. Please show a [mcve] of your code and show the error you got from that code.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this instead, since in SQL Agent `$( ... )`is reserved.

```
Import-Csv $DestinationFile | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "INSERT INTO $table VALUES ('$SourceFile','" + $_.LineNumber + "','" + $_.LineDescription + "','" + $_.Criteria + "','" + $_.LineValue + "')"
}
```